# Transfer data from one database to another MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 data bases in phpmyadmin and I need some help in the migration of data from one database to another.

1. First data base :
   Name of the database: ethernet
   Name of the table: data

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE ethernet.data(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    event TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    Count0 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Count1 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Count2 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    FPY VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
)
```

2. 2nd data base :
   Name of the database: ethernet1
   Name of the table: data1

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE ethernet1.data1(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    event TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    Count0 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Count1 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Count2 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    FPY VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
)
```

3. 3rd database:
   Name of the database: ethernet
   Name of the table: data

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE fpydcih.data2(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    event TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    FPYSVSL VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    FPYZ2FS VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
)
```

The ideea is to export last 10 values from the **ethernet.data** FPY column and last 10 values from **ethernet1.data1** FPY column and export them in the **fpydcih.data2** table.

Comment: What have you done so far and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

This is just to show the idea, I haven't checked it as I don't want to create 3 schemas.

```
SET @id1 = 0;
SET @id2 = 0;

INSERT INTO fpydcih.data2 (FPYSVSL, FPYZ2FS)
SELECT 
    t1.FPY FPYSVSL, t2.FPY FPYZ2FS 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT @id1 = @id1 + 1 id, FPY 
        FROM ethernet.data
        ORDER BY id DESC
        LIMIT 10
    ) t1
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT @id2 = @id2 + 1 id, FPY 
        FROM fpydcih.data2
        ORDER BY id DESC
        LIMIT 10
    ) t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
;
```

Comment: Now I have another issue , how can I made the same process of data extraction if the tables are in the same database

Comment: Just change the scheme names accordingly. There is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `union all`.  Something like this:

```
insert into fpydcih.data2 (id, event, count0, count1, count2, count3, fpa)
    (select id, event, count0, count1, count2, count3, fpa
     from ethernet.data
     order by event desc
     limit 10
    ) union all
    (select id, event, count0, count1, count2, count3, fpa
     from ethernet1.data1
     order by event desc
     limit 10
    );
```

You can also phrase this as two separate `insert`s.  Or if the destination table doesn't exist, use `create table as`.